# angular 2 img width sets to 0

Tags: image, angular, ionic2

So I am setting the image source and width dynamically in my template. The problem I see is that it sets the width to 0.

The template looks like:

```
<img src="{{item.msg}}" width="{{item.width}}" style="float:right" *ngIf="item.templateType == 'image'" />{{item.width}}
```

The value is passed as below from .ts

```
this.items.push(new ImageMessage('http://someimage.png', '100%'));
```

What I see is that it does not display the image but prints the value of item.width correctly. Looking into inspector it shows the width is set to 0 which explains why image is not appearing.

However, I am failing to understand why the width is getting set to 0 in img tag.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the width as a percentage using one-way binding syntax `[style.width.%]` targeting the `style` [attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#style-binding) of an element like `<img />` in your example. HTML5 does require that the `width` property is in pixels, so using the `[style.width.%]` attribute binding would allow you to set the width as a percentage.

You're ImageMssage object would need to have the percentage '%' character removed from the `width` value of the `ImageMessage` object to make this work. With this syntax, it's flexible to work with either strings or numbers. Either `'100'` or `100` would work.

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>

      <div *ngFor="let item of items">
        <img [src]="item.msg" [style.width.%]="item.width" style="float:right;" />
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  items: any[];

  constructor() {
    this.items = [
      { msg: 'http://placehold.it/800', width: '100' },
      { msg: 'http://placehold.it/800', width: '75' },
      { msg: 'http://placehold.it/800', width: 50 },
      { msg: 'http://placehold.it/800', width: '25' }
    ];
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, CommonModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

If you want to set the pixels, you can use the following:

```
<img [src]="item.msg" [style.width.px]="item.width" ... />{{item.width}}px
```

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/EK4PVc9GwMCvKp9GE6hn?p=preview) demonstrating the functionality.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think it may set the width to 0 because you have have 100% in single quotation marks. As in `{ width: '100%' }` try removing the quotation marks to produce `{ width: 100% }`. This may also explain why it prints the value of item.width.

Comment: just for the sake of not rigid i tried that. but it doesnt work. the issue isnot with quotation marks as it is setting the value to 0 not as '100%' etc. problem is the actual value being changed to 0

Comment: According to w3schools https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp, "In HTML5, the value must be in pixels."

Comment: that doesnt sound like good as for mobile devices i really cannot put in px